# Strange comments in code

Tags: comments

I have seen strange comments in code. For example what is the meaning or purpose of the following comments found [here](https://github.com/alexyoung/nodeinpractice/blob/master/listings/intro/first-project/index.js):

```
//<co id="callout-intro-countstream-index-1" />
//<co id="callout-intro-countstream-index-2" />
//<co id="callout-intro-countstream-index-3" />
//<co id="callout-intro-countstream-index-4" />
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a GitHub issue? I don't think so.

Comment: @Krish these are just comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is for the Manning Book *Node.js in Practice*. The comments indicate the callouts targets (i.e. numbered annotations) that the author references in the text while explaining the code listing.

It is DocBook formatting: http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/co.html

Comment: The author seems to be following a specific syntax for that. It seems source code for other Manning books are also following similar kind of syntax. Is it a standard syntax? Or internal to Manning?